# Visualforce Code - Modification

Tags: visualforce

What is the best way to identify to either chose the Enterprise_Account__c (if populated) and if not chose Main_Account__c...this would replace Account.ParentId.

```
<!-- Opptys in Account Hierarchy -->
<div style="overflow:hidden;"> 
<CRMC_PP:Grid ObjectName="Opportunity" FKName="Account.ParentId" FKValue="{!Account.Id}"  DelayLoad="false"  ViewID="a05P0000004rxZYIAY" 
EnableNewButton="true"  EnableNewInline="true"  EnableEdit="true"     EnableActions="true"  EnableFieldChooser="true" 
EnableStickyViews="true"  EnableToolbar="true"  EnableViews="true"  EnableFormatting="true"  EnableReadingPane="true" />
<CRMC_PP:DrillUp /> 
</div>
```

Comment: You wanna conditionally Select the value of FKName attribute, from 2 specified values?

Comment: @PranayJaiswal Yes, I would like this to be conditional.  If Enterprise Account = Null, then the Main Account needs to be queried.  I am going to remove the Account.ParentId as we are not using it.

Comment: @PranayJaiswal any additional ideas?

Comment: Nothing simpler than this :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional IF clause. Your code will look something similar

```
<CRMC_PP:Grid ObjectName="Opportunity" FKName="{!IF(Account.Enterprise_Account__c  !=null,'Main_Account__c','Account.ParentId')} " FKValue="{!Account.Id}"  />
<CRMC_PP:DrillUp />
```